# How to access BIOS ROM binary from linux shell

Tags: linux, shell, bios, firmware, rom

I want the binary code that is in ROM, to be made into general file in linux. So how to do it.
And also memory address where the ROM accessed?

Comment: Perhaps you can't, and probably you shouldn't. And why do you want it? Once Linux is running, the BIOS is useless....

Comment: Try to do something with info provided by `dmesg | grep BIOS`

Comment: It is to have better understanding for security

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible to read ROM BIOS content.**

- When your code is not under some protected mode OS like Linux
- for example, when you are in the boot mode. At that time ROM BIOS content is in the memory at 0x000F0000 address - take a look at IBM PC system architecture memory map: http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_(x86). So you can copy everything you need right from memory.

If you need ROM BIOS content only for study, you can use BIOS dump utilities - there are a lot of them.

You can check this utility [biosdecode](https://linux.die.net/man/8/biosdecode)

Check this utility also [flashrom](https://www.flashrom.org/Flashrom). Provided that your system is supported, you can read your BIOS content by issuing

```
flashrom -r outputfile
```

Another utility is dmidecode

```
dmidecode -t bios
```

Read the memory from C:0000 to F:FFFF without the need for dmidecode

**Sample command:**

```
dd if=/dev/mem bs=1k skip=768  count=256 2>/dev/null | strings -n 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Detailed instructions on obtainning the image can be found in `libreboot` [docs](https://libreboot.org/docs/install/spi.html). Be prepared to disassemble your device to attach an external `spi` programmer in the worst (my) case.

I've found this question looking for a tools to see what's inside that image. `fiano` [project](https://github.com/linuxboot/fiano) is the one I needed.

`utk image.rom table` prints the contents table of the `image.rom` dump.